# microsoft word and call rejected by callee

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word

I have word incorporated in my winform and I get the following error:

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010001): Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.Activate()
```

when the code execute the line of code "doc.ActiveWindow". Does anyone know or have any idea of how to catch this exception and not display it or how to resolve it? I've been banging my head on this for a few days and is stuck.